# How to represent message mappings / transformations?

Tags: mapping, uml, diagram, message

I would like to have a more or less formal way of representing how messages are consumed by different components in a system and how they are transformed by those.

I have done some kind of master data matrix in Excel, but it's difficult to represent some kinds of relationships, such as field mappings between messages.

Is there any UML approach to this? DFDs are not really message oriented, hence not helpful for this scenario

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why UML communication diagrams and/or sequence diagrams won't do?

Comment: Maybe I didn't express the question properly, but I want to focus more in the content of the messages (what fields are read/updated by what systems). Also to note: those messages can have tens of fields

Answer (score 0):

First, you must define your messages using class diagrams, each message being one class. Then you can do an activity diagram to show how the messages flow between the systems. Then for each system, create a sequence diagram that describes how the system interacts with the message.

Don't we love UML's complexity? :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I was expecting something that could give an immediate overview in a much simpler way. For example, I have a matrix where I set what fields of a message are created/read/updated/forwarded by what system. The problem comes with mapped or referenced fields (where, for example, a field name is different in another message although the content is the same)

I guess I'll have to use a few matrices... or we can invent some new UML artifact :D

Comment: Yea, another UML artifact is just what we need. Like we don't have enough of them alreay :-)

Comment: Yes, and in the end no one reads them, they just look cool in a PPT